# How do I get a grandchild to use the grandparent <router-outlet> in angular 6

Tags: angular, routes, angular6, parent-child

I have an example of what I'm looking for at this stack blitz:
[https://angular-czk5vj.stackblitz.io/](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-czk5vj?file=src%2Fapp%2Femployees%2Freport-detail%2Freport-detail.component.ts)

Basically what I'm trying to do is get the grand child route to render in the grand parent router-outlet.

ie
Routes:
Employees
---> Emp-Reports
------>Report-Detail

View

When Clicking on the name in the first column, it routes to the employee's reports in the second column.  When clicking on the report in the second column, it displays the report details in the third column.

The reason I feel I need this done in routing is I want to be able to send the exact report via url (employees/11/reportdetail/2) so the app can open on that report. I'm open to another method to accomplishing this.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some serious concerns of naming conventions in your implementation. So I decided to create my own. It doesn't have the Lazy Loading of Modules but that's something you already know and can achieve.

Coming back to your requirement, you can implement each level as a Child Route to the previous level. So each component template that is a parent will have a `router-outlet` tag in it.

So your `routes` config can look something like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'employees', component: EmployeesComponent, children: [
    { path: ':id', component: ReportsComponent, children: [
      { path: 'detail/:repId', component: DetailsComponent },
      { path: '**', component: PlaceholderComponent }
    ] },
    { path: '**', component: PlaceholderComponent }
  ] },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/employees', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

Notice that here I also have a `PlaceholderComponent` that will be displayed if an item needs to be selected from the list.

I've used Bootstraps Grids to manage the distribution of the content in three columns. That's all you'll need.

---

Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-three-level-details-on-the-same-page?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) for your ref.

Comment: Very detailed explanation on routing children concepts sidd.  Keep the good work.

Comment: @SiddAjmera...thank you so much.  Yes, the naming in my stack blitz wasn't pretty.  It was a quick and dirty setup so I could get something running that mimicked the issues I was having.  Anyway, this is exactly what I was looking to get.  I tried the children route before and couldn't get it to work... I'll look at your code and figure out where I went wrong..

Comment: Just to followup, one item that is different than my original is the where the router-outlet element is placed.  I put my all in the one view.  Clearly the child didn't know about the 'third' outlet and wouldn't place it.  moving the outlet to the child, then using the bootstrap css did the trick.

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya I know this question is rather old, but I'm facing a similar issue. The only difference is that I need to display each and every children, grandchildren, grand-grandchildren (and so on...) component in the same `router-outlet` which is inside the template of the root component. Is it possible to do such that?